# Android Vision reading ean-13 barcodes from bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, barcode, android-vision

I'm trying to read barcodes from a picture but i can only read QR codes? I've, as you can see from the code below, tried to make the bitmap a higher res as I hoped that it was the image resolution that made the image unreadable. But that didn't help.

Barcode activity:

```
    package lassebjoerklund.easyfridge;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class BarcodeTracking extends Activity {
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private Bitmap image;
    private BarcodeDetector detector;
    private ImageView scanedImage;
    private Uri mImageUri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_tracking);

        scanedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivScanedImage);

        detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();


        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photo = new File("");
        try {
            photo = createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
            photo.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(getApplication().getClass().getSimpleName(), "Can't create file to take picture!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check SD card! Image shot is impossible!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            grabImage(scanedImage);
            if(image != null) {
                this.grabImage(scanedImage);
                if (!detector.isOperational()) {
                    Log.d("Detector Setup", "could not setup detector");
                } else {
                    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
                    SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
                    if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                        Barcode resultedBarcode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
                        Log.d("Barcode", "" + resultedBarcode.rawValue);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception {
        File tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        tempDir = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/.temp/");
        if (!tempDir.exists()) {
            tempDir.mkdir();
        }
        return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
    }

    private void grabImage(ImageView imageView) {
        this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(mImageUri, null);
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mImageUri);
            image = bitmap;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(getApplication().getClass().getSimpleName(), "Failed to load", e);
        }
    }


}
```

I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.. Can anyone help ?

**Update**

Found out that it's working on a Gs6 edge, but not on my nexus 5... both running 6.0.1 android

**Update 2**

Got it working, for now. The problem was the distance to the image. Instead of holding the phone 5 cm from the code, I've tried a little longer away.

But i will still leve the question open, in case something finds a mistake in the code